# Convert epub to epub, to do more heuristic processing

Tags: calibre, file-format

During format conversion, Calibre can perform some heuristic processing.
For example detecting chapters and scenebreaks.

I've notices that a few epubs (especially from Project Gutenberg),
could really do with that kind of heuristic processing.
For example their chapters may not all be separated.

Is there a way I can execute the heuristic processing part of conversion without actually doing any conversion?

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the command-line tool

[[Manual]](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html)

If you use the command-line tool,
you can do just this.
Though you need to make sure the input filename and the output filename differ.

for example

```
ebook-convert myorig.epub mybetter.epub --heuristic-processing
```

Comment: Note: the correct flag is now `--enable-heuristics`.